# Concatenate Js/Css plugin breaks paths in LESS files

Tags: plugins, less, concatenation, impresspages

I have just installed the Concatenate Js/Css plugin and a couple of paths inside my less files become broken within the resulting CSS.

**For example:**

this path 
  url('/Theme/PrimoCargo-Bootstrap/assets/img/home_header-image.jpg')

becomes this
url('http://www.primocargo.de/Theme/PrimoCargo-Bootstrap/assets//Theme/PrimoCargo-Bootstrap/assets/img/home_header-image.jpg')

So it adds the complete path adding a trailing slash although this option is off in the admin section of IP.

Where am I thinking wrong?

Thank you & cheers to all, 
Tom

*PS. Nginx runs in PHP 7.*

Answer (score 0):

`Concatenate JS/CSS` plugin doesn't change any paths. It just puts all contents to one file.